# handling focus and blur event in angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Recently I was working in an angular js project. I happens to face a situation in which I need to handle focus and blur events textbox. My scenario is that I need to append $ sign when focus is out from textbox and append $ when textbox is focused.

I tried to create component for that

```
       angular.module('myApp').component('dollarText', {
          templateUrl: '<input type="text">',
          controller: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs){
                iElm.bind('change', function(){
                    iElm.val('$'+iElm.val());
                });
            }
        });
```

But I cant access focus event. I know I was not doing it correct. 
How can I trigger both focus and blur in angular component. Is angular component best choice for my task.

Comment: use `currency` filter?

Comment: How can I put currency filter in textbox focus and blur. Want to append $ when focus is out. When textbox focused want to remove $. This $ should not be come in validation. Validation should be numeric. I am new to angular thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle a certain `div` or other, for example, in an `ng-repeat` or in a long list of element, you need to use `function(this)` and on JavaScript side you need to use `function(context)` to interact with that element.

[Here's a working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wgqGFGMb7F7b222iVUEh) of what I suppose you are looking for.

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <!--When on-blur, call blur(this), when on-focus, call focus(this)-->
    <input type="text" name="myApplicationRocks" 
           ng-focus="focus(this)" ng-blur="blur(this)"/>
       <!-- Content changes on blur and on focus-->
       <h1>{{whatToWrite}}</h1>
  </body>  
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
  
  $scope.whatToWrite = "Well, try something";
  
  $scope.focus = function(context){
    console.log("On Focus");
    context.whatToWrite = "Focus On!";
  };
  
  $scope.blur = function(context){
    console.log("On Blur");
    context.whatToWrite = "Blur On!";
  };
});
```

Of course it will work also without `this` and `context` but in certain situations it is very useful.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Can I use this as a component. That is the logic inside controller of component

Comment: If you mean accessing a precise item that lies inside other items yea, just using `this` and `context`. Try and let me know If you need help.

Comment: tried this code but focus is not triggering                app.component('dollarText',{
  template: '<input type="text" ng-focus="focus(this)" ng-blur="blur(this)">',
  controller: function($scope) {
    // this.user = {name: 'world'};

    this.focus=function(context){
     console.log('entered');
    }

    this.blur=function(context){
     console.log('left');
    }
  }
})

Comment: Try putting everything into a Plunker so I can help you.

Comment: @ AndreaM16 I got it. Thanks for your support